# Laravel response includes wrong json script

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Does any one know when fetching data using ajax laravel appends an additional script tag.
Like : 
 is unwanted script dont know from where it appends this script.

**/vendor/composer/installed.js** this wraps inside script tag

```
{"total":1055,"rows":[[1,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2102\">1805623<\/a>","IGT","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2102\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2102)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[2,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2101\">1805623<\/a>","IGT","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2101\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2101)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[3,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2100\">1805623<\/a>","IGT","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2100\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2100)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[4,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2099\">NG001459<\/a>","Nova","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2099\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2099)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[5,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2098\">NG002325<\/a>","Nova","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2098\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2098)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[6,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2097\">NG002329<\/a>","Nova","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2097\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2097)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[7,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2096\">040486US<\/a>","ARUZE","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2096\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2096)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[8,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2095\">W2186717<\/a>","Williams","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2095\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2095)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[9,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2094\">B106874398<\/a>","Bally","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2094\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2094)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[10,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2093\">50427<\/a>","AGS","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2093\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2093)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"]]}
```

Above is the json response i am getting.
Please help me to get out of it.
Thanks

Comment: That file for me is a `.json` file without any script tags. If you're getting it as a `.js` file somehow, perhaps it's automatically wrapping the json in the tags. Do you have some sample code of how you're trying to retrieve this in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

JSON automatically adds escaped characters to its string. However you can use json_decode to get the proper data. Below is the example:

```
$json = '{"total":1055,"rows":[[1,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2102\">1805623<\/a>","IGT","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2102\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2102)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[2,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2101\">1805623<\/a>","IGT","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2101\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2101)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[3,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2100\">1805623<\/a>","IGT","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2100\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2100)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[4,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2099\">NG001459<\/a>","Nova","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2099\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2099)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[5,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2098\">NG002325<\/a>","Nova","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2098\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2098)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[6,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2097\">NG002329<\/a>","Nova","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2097\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2097)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[7,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2096\">040486US<\/a>","ARUZE","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2096\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2096)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[8,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2095\">W2186717<\/a>","Williams","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2095\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2095)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[9,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2094\">B106874398<\/a>","Bally","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2094\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2094)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"],[10,"<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/showMachine\/2093\">50427<\/a>","AGS","On Floor","<a href=\"http:\/\/portal.igsgamingsolutions.com\/editMachine\/2093\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-pencil\"><\/i><\/a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href=\"javascript:void(0);\" onclick=\"deleteMachine(2093)\"><i aria-hidden=\"true\" class=\"icon wb-trash\"><\/i><\/a>"]]}';
dd(json_decode($json, true)); /* 'true' returns array data */
```

Hope this helps you. :)